# mysqlpp: SQL syntax error when using template queries

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql++

I tried to use template queries to construct my sql query. Here's the sample code:

```
unsigned int version = 2;
try {
    // key_version is INT UNSIGNED
    mysqlpp::Query query = conn->query("SELECT * FROM agentlist WHERE key_version != %0q");
    mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store(version);
    // string type param also caused the same problem
    // mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store(std::to_string(version));
} catch (const exception &ex) {
    // deal with exceptions
}
```

And the code would go to `catch` part. `ex.what()`:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'2\' at line 1

I think it was caused by `SQLQueryParms` type, but the neither the tutorial nor the documentation had shown any methods to work around this.

BTW, how do I get parsed query string (with template params substituted)? I tried `query.str(version)` but it was same as `query.str()`.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Forgot an important function call `query.parse()`.

And it all works now.